# How to transfer values between multiple threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm

In java:

```
 r1=complexCalc1();
 r2=complexCalc2();
 r3=complexCalc3();
 r4=complexCalc4();
 r5=complexCalc5();
 return r1+r2+r3+r4+r5;
```

Assume running times like

```
complexCalc1() -> 5 mins 
complexCalc2() -> 3 mins
complexCalc3() -> 2 mins
complexCalc4() -> 4 mins
complexCalc5() -> 9 mins
```

if this program had run sequentially it would take 23
minutes for calculating r1+r2+r3+r4+r5. If each function had run parallely i.e. each 
complexCalc() function in separate threads total time taken would be 9 mins for r1+r2+r3+r4+r5 computation.

My question is how to achieve it.. I tried several methods but i still
cant figure out anything concrete.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a loot at Executors and Futures and all the goodies in [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)

Comment: Just as a note, it's not necessarily the case that you will get a perfect amount of concurrency.  If each of these calculations has its own core to run on and there is no coordination necessary, you might get close to the ideal, but even then, no guarantees.

Answer (score 2):

A rough draft of the solution, using only standard Java API, looks like this:

```
public class Main {
    private static final Callable<Integer> createCalculationSimulator (final int result, final int minutesToWait) {
        return new Callable<Integer> () {
            @Override
            public Integer call() throws Exception {
                Thread.sleep(minutesToWait*60*1000L);
                return result;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
        final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool (5);
        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final List<Future<Integer>> results = executorService.invokeAll(
            Arrays.asList(
                createCalculationSimulator(1, 5),
                createCalculationSimulator(2, 3),
                createCalculationSimulator(3, 2),
                createCalculationSimulator(4, 4),
                createCalculationSimulator(5, 9)));

        int resultSum = 0;
        for (final Future<Integer> result : results) {
            resultSum += result.get();
        }
        final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("The end result is " + resultSum + ". Time needed = " + (endTime - startTime)/1000 + " seconds.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing the `executorService.shutdown()` method here.  Also, it's important to explain that the `result.get()` might throw if the `call()` method throws.

Answer (score 1):

If you can divide the task into logical **independent tasks** (which I believe you can as you already indicated) then it is fairly easy with Java 5+.

- Implement each task in its own Callable
- Submit all of them to the Executor. [ExecutorService.invokeAll(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29)
- The above step returns a List which you will store and make sure all of them are completed (Look at the api)

**Note**

- Initialize the thread pool size to be equal to the number of cores (Of-course, you tune after you profile.
- If you can have external dependency then I suggest using [Guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) that simplifies the usage of Executors.